Data inserted in Fierestore doesn't show up in the UI with React Native
I'm inserting data in Firestore DB but it doesn't show up in the Firestore UI. But when I run the query using the react-native library I get results back. Anyone know why this might be happening?
These are the logs:
 LOG  Total users:  15
 LOG  User ID:  00HxI74CXbjk54IaFOiu {"age": 39, "name": "Fernando"}
 LOG  User ID:  2rBtzjf9W9cCfADx20V6 {"age": 39, "name": "Fernando"}
 LOG  User ID:  99YNpKHMIcTls9PYKGQ9 {"age": 39, "name": "Fernando"}
 LOG  User ID:  P1XF5ICg6KgcDYyA069j {"age": 39, "name": "Fernando"}
 LOG  User ID:  Pm18VRl9Tl0ES6sDF7oT {"age": 39, "name": "Fernando"}
...

And this is my code:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

// Configuración de Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Inicializar Firebase
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  console.log('Initializing Firebase');
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  console.log('Firebase already initialized');
}

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log('Firestore instance:', firestore());
  }, []);
  
  const addUser = async () => {
    console.log('adding user');
    console.log(firestore().app.name);

    const usersRef = firestore().collection('Users');
    usersRef.add({
      name: 'Fernando',
      age: 39,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('User added!');
    });

     usersRef
      // Filter results
      .where('age', '==', 39)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        console.log('Total users: ', querySnapshot.size);
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
          console.log('User ID: ', documentSnapshot.id, documentSnapshot.data());
        });

      });

    console.log('done');
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Add User to Firestore</Text>
      <Button title="Add User" onPress={addUser} />
    </View>
  );
}

Also something that I don't understand is when I log the app name => console.log(firestore().app.name); I get the following: LOG  [DEFAULT].

what do you mean it's not in the Firestore UI? But you already retrieved data from their according to your logs?

Yes, results are coming back but I don't know where they are stored because when I open the Firebase Console -> Firestore Database I don't see those results in there.

Is there a way to enable the debug logging in Firestore on React Native? Similar to this - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#setloglevel_d02fda2

If the data doesn't show up in the Firestore web console, but does show up in your application's UI, it likely means that the data is (only) stored in the local cache. This usually means that your device/app is not able to communicate with the Firestore server, and your write operations are all pending.
You can verify this by checking the metadata.hasPendingWrites property in the DocumentSnapshot object.
To find out why the code isn't able to send the write to the server, check your app/device's internet connection and configuration data.
